# Can i pass props from a child component to parent in Astro?

Tags: javascript, astrojs

Please tell me is it possible to pass props from a child `Astro` component to the parent? Something like callback in `React`:

```
<Component callBack={arg=>{
  //do something with arg
}} />
```

Are there some analogues in `Astro`? Thanks for attention!

Comment: do you want to pass some state? or method?

Comment: I just want to pass some values, - like input or checkbox to parent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Props can only flow downward in Astro, the closest you can get to doing something like what your describing is [passing arguments to slot functions](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/api-reference/#astroslotsrender)

Example from the docs:

```
// src/components/Shout.astro
---
const message = Astro.props.message.toUpperCase();
---
{ Astro.slots.has('default') &&
  <Fragment set:html={Astro.slots.render('default', [message])} />
}
```

```
// src/pages/index.astro
---
import Shout from "../components/Shout.astro";
---
<Shout message="slots!">
  {(message) => <div>{message}</div>}
</Shout>
```

renders into

```html
<div>SLOTS!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't pass props from `child` component to `parent` component. if you want to expose some methods of `child` component to `parent` you can use `useImperativeHandle` hook.

```
function Form() {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  function handleClick() {
    ref.current.focus();    // focus is method from `child
  }

  return (
    <form>
      <MyInput label="Enter your name:" ref={ref} />
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Edit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}

const MyInput = forwardRef(function MyInput(props, ref) {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      focus() {
        inputRef.current.focus();
      },
      scrollIntoView() {
        inputRef.current.scrollIntoView();
      },
    };
  }, []);

  return <input {...props} ref={inputRef} />;
});
```

[Reference](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useImperativeHandle)

Comment: This is react, not astro